# Where in the FIPS documents is it stated that SHA-1 is not secure?

Tags: reference-request, sha-1, standards, fips-140

SHA-1 has not been secure for a very long time, but I still can see
[it here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf).

Where in the FIPS documents did it state that SHA-1 is not secure?

Comment: [Here](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/FR_Notice_Nov07.pdf) is the paper introduction the SHA-3 competition. While it does not say that SHA-1 is not secure, it motivates the competition. [Here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-131Ar1.pdf) is a paper from NIST about the transition.

Comment: There are various NIST documents that say SHA-1 will be disallowed because it does not meet 112-bit security, which was specified as the minimum for certain applications after specific dates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much of what NIST publishes about cryptographic algorithms is in Special Publications. In this case it is [SP 800-131](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-131Ar1.pdf) (pdf) where they describe transitioning away from old algorithms and key sizes.

Pages 14-15 have the hash function specific information:

> SHA-1 for digital signature generation:
>
> SHA-1 may only be used for digital signature generation where specifically allowed by NIST protocol-specific guidance. For all other applications, SHA-1 **shall not** be used for digital signature generation.
>
> SHA-1 for digital signature verification:
>
> For digital signature verification, SHA-1 is allowed for **legacy-use**.
>
> SHA-1 for non-digital signature applications:
>
> For all other hash function applications, the use of SHA-1 is **acceptable**. The other applications include HMAC, Key Derivation Functions (KDFs), Random Bit Generation, and hash-only applications (e.g., hashing passwords and using SHA-1 to compute a checksum, such as the approved integrity technique specified in Section 4.6.1 of [FIPS 140]).

FIPS 140, being the document you linked in the question, points to this document for guidance.

Comment: Allowing "SHA-1 to compute a checksum" seems like a dubious idea, since those can easily depend on collision resistance.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, maybe it means non-cryptographic integrity protection? The section 4.6.1 "integrity test" seems to allow use of an error detection code, so it is presumably only meant to catch non-malicious errors.

Comment: Is this still true in 2022?